# Stumped by 'no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "character"' error

Tags: r, lapply, tidy

I have a data frame with two relevant columns: name, id

I have a list of regexes which I'd like to match against the values in the name column and return the id value on the same row.

It works if I pass a single value, but when I try lapply, I get this error:

Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "character"

```
id <- c(1:10)

name <- c("a_able", "b_baker", "c_charlie", "d_delta", "e_echo", "f_foxtrot", "g_golf", "h_hotel", "i_indigo", "j_juliet")

t <- tibble(id, name)

prefix <- c("^c_", "^f_", "^g_")

matchingName <- function(tibbleName, pattern){
       return(tibbleName %>% filter(str_detect(name, pattern)) %>% select(id))
}

matchingName(t, prefix[1])
# A tibble: 1 x 1
       id
    <int>
1       3

lapply(prefix, matchingName, t)
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
   no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "character"
Called from: filter_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...))
```

I expect to get a list of ids (3,6,7).
I get the error message instead.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, problem with argument specification.